# xrdp connection from external network.

Tags: remote-access, firewall, xrdp

I have a Ubuntu machine that I would like external users to connect to using RDP. Connecting from an internal network works perfectly fine.

But users outside of my network can not connect. What could be the reason?

Note that I have checked the following already:

- Port 3389 is listening to incoming connections

  `sudo netstat -an | grep "LISTEN" | grep ":3389"`

  `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3389            0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN`
- If it is a Firewall relevant issue I have issued the following command

  `sudo ufw disable`

  `Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup`
- I have installed Ubuntu mate, and it works fine when connecting from a computer internal to the network
- I have issued the `sudo service xrdp restart command`

Answer (score 0):

External users need to connect using SSH